# Export mongodb aggregation framework result to a new collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to save the aggregation framework result to a new collection.
I know that's impossible with the framework at the moment with the command itself.

Is there a workaround in the shell?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update:** See Salvador's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19600746/1259510) for a more efficient way to do this in MongoDB 2.6+.

---

Save the aggregation result in a variable and then insert its `result` property into a new collection:

```js
var result = db.foo.aggregate(...);
db.bar.insert(result.result);
```

Comment: Only bummer is needing to hold all the result values in memory.  See [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3253) for the issue regarding `$out`.

Comment: Also, that result set needs to fit in the standard MongoDB document size (16MB).

Comment: @AidanFeldman: The Aggregation inline result is [already limited](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/#result) to the maximum BSON document size.

Comment: @Stennie luckily not for long, 2.6 will address this.

Comment: I was able to do the following:
db.foo.aggregate(...).forEach(function(it){db.bar.insert(it);}); I'm not sure if this is more efficient though.

Answer (score 48):

Starting with **Mongo 2.6.0** you can do this natively without any additional manipulation.

```
db.<collection>.aggregate( [
     { <operation> },
     { <operation> },
     ...,
     { $out : "<output-collection>" }
] )
```

Check the new aggregation operator [$out](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) for more detailed example.

**P.S.** using this way you are not limited to 16Mb size.

Comment: So what to do you pre 2.6?  I need to get around the 16Mb limit and still create a new collection using aggregation pipeline on 2.4.

Comment: Again, need to get around 16mb limit though.  Was working on a 2.4 instance.  Used a `find()`, `foreach()`, `insert()` successfully.

Comment: Related to the limits, is there still an upper limit of the data that can be written to the new collection in terms of size or document count?

Answer (score 1):

result.result is no longer working, try toArray().

```
var result  = db.coll.aggregate(...);
db.bar.insert(result.toArray());
```