# Inserting large collection into another collection

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection of 30000 documents of the form:

```
<_id:X src: 1 , dst:2}
<_id:X src: 1 , dst:3}
<_id:X src: 1 , dst:4}
<_id:X src: 1 , dst:5}
<_id:X src: 1 , dst:6}
<_id:X src: 1 , dst:7}
...
```

I transform this collection into the following form:

```
<_id: 1 , listOfNumbers:[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
<_id: 2 , dst:0}
<_id: 3 , dst:0}
<_id: 5 , dst:0}
<_id: 7 , dst:0}
<_id: 9 , dst:0}
...
```

I do this by using a MapReduce operation and the push method and it takes 12s to convert 10000 documents, 75s to convert 20000 documents.

Does anybody know how this could be done faster? Do indexes play a role here?

Thank you!

Comment: Why dont' you use the MongoDB aggregation framework for this?

Comment: Besides the fact I don't know what that is, I am pretty sure I shouldn't use it. :)

Comment: Perhaps you want to google for Mongodb+Aggregation+Framework instead of posting such dumb followups

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't wan't to offend you. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I have to use the MapReduce approach for solving this problem. That was what I meant.

Comment: You have to use MR? Why???? Three good reasons

Comment: I looked at the aggregation framework. It is super fast, but it lacks the ability to save the result directly to MongoDB.

Comment: You didn't look particularly hard - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612028/export-mongodb-aggregation-framework-result-to-a-new-collection

Comment: I meant directly to MongoDB, without using JS (problem with converting 30000 documents).

Comment: 'without using JS' - How do you propose to communicate with the MongoDB instance?

Comment: Sorry, I slipped again. I meant without using JavaScript variables.

Comment: what's the problem with javascript variables? It's either keep your mapreduce, use the aggregation framework, or write some kind of script in your chosen language to iterate over the docs in your collection, saving to a new collection. Obviously #3 is slowest, and least recommended way

Comment: If you are fetching the data out of Mongo then inserting it back in again you're introducing additional network latency which will slow your process down, especially with so much data to process. As @alexjamesbrown suggests, you would be best off using the aggregation framework so it all happens on the server.

Comment: And a partial answer to your question, indexes will only play a part if you are querying by a particular field on the documents (src?) which you don't specify. Without seeing the code you are using to query it's hard to tell.