# mongoexport aggregate export to a csv file

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I want to save the result from an aggregation into a csv file.

Using the mongo cmd line tool I can do this to get the results I want:

```
db.compras.aggregate({ $group : { _id : "$data.proponente", total : { $sum : "$price" } }}
```

How would I translate this into a mongoexport command that saves results into a csv?

Comment: FYI, `mongoexport` has `--query` option, but it doesn't support complex queries like yours.

Comment: so there is no way to do it?

Comment: could you solve this problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't run [aggregate()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/) queries through `mongoexport`. The `mongoexport` tool is intended for more basic data export with a query filter rather than full aggregation and data processing.  You could easily write a short script using your favourite [language driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/) for MongoDB, though.

Answer (score 158):

Slightly simpler option as of 2.6+ is to now add an `$out` step to your aggregate to put the results into a collection:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [ { aggregation steps... }, { $out : "results" } ] )
```

Then just use `mongoexport` as:

```
mongoexport -d database -c results -f field1,field2,etc --csv > results.csv
```

After that you might want to delete the temporary collection from the database so that it does not keep using unnecessary resources, and also to avoid confusion later, when you have forgotten why this collection exists in your database.

```
db.results.drop()
```

Comment: I tried this from within Robo 3T and it failed. However, when using the mongo shell directly this was like wonderful magic.

Comment: It's worth all the efforts without the use of a client. But then I had faced a weird issue making use of this query  - [Mongo aggregate query results in less document with sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60897584/mongo-aggregate-query-results-in-less-document-with-sorting) which I doubt wouldn't have been the case with a client. (Though I am not completely sure of the comparison there.)

Comment: flag --csv deprecated

Comment: @Omar Aziz use: `--type=csv`

Answer (score 55):

You can export to a CSV file with the following 3 steps:

1. Assign your aggregation results to a variable ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13612266/1745902)):

   ```
   var result = db.compras.aggregate({ $group : { _id : "$data.proponente", total : { $sum : "$price" } }}
   ```
2. Insert a value of the variable to a new collection:

   ```
   db.bar.insert(result.toArray());
   ```
3. In terminal (or command line) export this **bar** collection to a CSV file:

   ```
   mongoexport -d yourdbname -c bar -f _id,total --csv > results.csv
   ```

...and you're done :)

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 can be combined as of MongoDB 2.6 using the $out operator on aggregate. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612028/export-mongodb-aggregation-framework-result-to-a-new-collection/19600746#19600746.

Comment: This is really helpful for people still stuck with 2.4 on their servers. Upvoted.

Comment: I believe step two should be db.bar.insert(result.toArray());

Answer (score 20):

If you don't want to store the results in a collection, you could also write directly to a CSV file from JavaScript using the print function.  Save the following script to a file like exportCompras.js.

```
let cursor = db.compras.aggregate({ $group : 
  { _id : "$data.proponente", 
    total : { $sum : "$price" }
  }
});

if (cursor && cursor.hasNext()) {

  //header
  print('proponente,total');

  cursor.forEach(item => {
    print('"' + item._id + '",' + item.total);
    // printjson(item); -- if you need JSON
  });
}
```

From the command line, call
>mongo server/collection exportCompras.js > comprasResults.csv --quiet

Updated from [@M.Justin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108305/m-justin) comment to replace the previous while loop.

Comment: This could be simplified using `.forEach` rather than manually iterating over the cursor: `cursor.forEach(item => print('"' + item._id + '",' + item.total));`

Comment: For the current code, just need a ) after the forEach block above

Answer (score 5):

Take the following and save it on the mongo server somewhere:

```
// Export to CSV function
DBCommandCursor.prototype.toCsv = function(deliminator, textQualifier) 
{
    var count = -1;
    var headers = [];
    var data = {};

    deliminator = deliminator == null ? ',' : deliminator;
    textQualifier = textQualifier == null ? '\"' : textQualifier;

    var cursor = this;

    while (cursor.hasNext()) {

        var array = new Array(cursor.next());

        count++;

        for (var index in array[0]) {
            if (headers.indexOf(index) == -1) {
                headers.push(index);
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (var index in array[i]) {
                data[count + '_' + index] = array[i][index];
            }
        }
    }

    var line = '';

    for (var index in headers) {
        line += textQualifier + headers[index] + textQualifier + deliminator;
    }

    line = line.slice(0, -1);
    print(line);

    for (var i = 0; i < count + 1; i++) {

        var line = '';
        var cell = '';
        for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
            cell = data[i + '_' + headers[j]];
            if (cell == undefined) cell = '';
            line += textQualifier + cell + textQualifier + deliminator;
        }

        line = line.slice(0, -1);
        print(line);
    }
}
```

Then you can run the following commands via the shell or a GUI like Robomongo:

```
load('C:\\path\\to\\your\\saved\\js\\file')
db.compras.aggregate({ $group : { _id : "$data.proponente", total : { $sum : "$price" } }}.toCsv();
```

Answer (score 2):

By the same logic, in my case, I want the output as JSON data into **out.json**

1- Create **file.js** *on local, not on the server*

```
date = new Date("2019-09-01");
query = {x: true, 'created': {$gte: date}};
now = new Date();
userQuery = {'user.email': {$nin: [/\.dev$|@test\.com$|@testing\.com$/]}};
data = db.companies.aggregate([
    {$match: query},
    {$sort: {x: 1, created: 1}},
    {$lookup: {as: 'user', from: 'users', localField: 'creator', foreignField: '_id'}},
    {$addFields: {user: {$arrayElemAt: ['$user', 0]}}},
    {$match: userQuery},
    {$project: {"_id": 1, "name": 1, "user.email": 1, "xyz": 1}}
]).toArray();

print(JSON.stringify(data));
```

2- Run

```
mongo server/collection file.js > out.json --quiet
```

3- Delete header and check **out.json**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "124564789",
    "xyz": [
      {
        "name": "x",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "name": "y",
        "value": "2"
      }
    ],
    "name": "LOL",
    "user": {
      "email": "LOL@LOL.com"
    }
  },
....
....
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for query-

```
mongoexport -d DataBase_Name -c Collection_Name --type=csv --fields name,phone,email -q '{_bank:true,"bank.ifsc":{$regex:/YESB/i}}' --out report.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the export as suggested, but I'm getting csv flag deprecated

so
here is a working snippet

```sh
mongoexport -d database_name -c collection_name -f field1,field_2 --type=csv > results.csv
```

Optionally, you can add a filter like the following

```sh
mongoexport -h 0.0.0.0 -d database_name -c collection_name --query '{"$or": [{"condition_one": true},{"condition_two": true}]}' --type=csv --fields "field1,field_2" > out.csv
```