# MongoDB aggregate export to CSV

Tags: mongodb, export-to-csv

I was looking at this thread: [mongoexport aggregate export to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468602/mongoexport-aggregate-export-to-a-csv-file)

and I was able to use the suggested `.toCsv()` with `db.collection.find()`
but I am unable to use it with `db.collection.aggregate().toCsv()`

It gives me an error:

> TypeError: ...toCsv() is not a function. Details: $(shell):1:1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: fwiw, the second answer to that question (using $out) seems like a better approach. (I think the first answer was written before mongo 2.6 added $out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script that you're using is monkey-patching `DBCommandCursor.prototype.toCsv` to add the `toCsv` method to cursors, and it seems like that doesn't work for aggregation cursors for some reason (and doesn't work at all on the version of mongo I'm running).

Rather than figuring out why the mongo shell isn't behaving the way that you'd like, one **dangerous** approach would be to instead monkey-patch the `Array.prototype`

```js
Array.prototype.toCSV = function toMediocreCSV () {
  const results = this;
  const headers = {};
  results.forEach((result) =>
    Object.keys(result).forEach((key) => headers[key] = true)
  )
  const keys = Object.keys(headers);
  print(keys.join(","));
  results.forEach((result) =>
    print(keys.map((key) => result[key] != null ? result[key] : '')
      .join(",")) 
  )
}
> db.test.aggregate().toArray().toCSV()
_id,a,b,c
ObjectId("5d1a77e1688b8f1d66098375"),1,2,
ObjectId("5d1a77e1688b8f1d66098376"),3,,4
```

Alternatively, you could write a similar function that takes in an array and formats it the way that you'd like: the only benefit to modifying the prototype would be the ability to chain things nicely.

Comment: I have modified your code to accommodate for a textQualifier. Otherwise, it messes with the columns if there is a key with array.  `Array.prototype.toCSV = function toMediocreCSV () {
  const results = this;
  const headers = {};
  results.forEach((result) =>
    Object.keys(result).forEach((key) => headers[key] = true)
  )
  const keys = Object.keys(headers);
  print("\'"+keys.join("\',\'")+"\'");
  results.forEach((result) =>
    print("\'"+keys.map((key) => result[key] != null ? result[key] : '')
      .join("\',\'")+"\'") 
  )
};`

Answer (score 0):

Hey there the mongo command is telling you that toCVS

the solution I prefer is the following

```
var result = db.compras.aggregate()
```

then you put your result into a collection

```
db.agr.insert(result.result);
```

the use mongoexport

```
mongoexport -d yourdbname -c agr -f _id,total --csv > results.csv
```

Comment: This seems a very complicated approach considering that I have to modify my aggregation, add to a collection, mongoexport it, search for the exported file, etc. instead I could just add .toCsv() at the end and the results are ready for copy/paste in Excel. I am using this sort of exports a lot in my work and using mongoexport is very time consuming for me.