# How can i optimize my query i have written to find the Users and there last order details using aggregate, it shows me timeout as the dataset is large

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a query as below, what it does it creates a link between two documents and find the last order date and users details like email, phone, etc. but on large data set it shows me timeout error any help would be much appreciated, and thanks in advance for the help

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "orders",
      "let": {
        "id": "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$addFields": {
            "owner": {
              "$toObjectId": "$owner"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$owner",
                "$$id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        
      ],
      "as": "orders"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$orders",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false,
      includeArrayIndex: "arrayIndex"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "order": {
        "$last": "$orders.createdAt"
        
      },
      "userInfo": {
        "$mergeObjects": {
          name: "$name",
          email: "$email",
          phone: "$phone",
          orderCount: "$orderCount"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      name: "$userInfo.name",
      email: "$userInfo.email",
      phone: "$userInfo.phone",
      orderCount: "$userInfo.orderCount",
      lastOrder: "$order",
      
    }
  }
]
)
```

my documents look like the following for orders

```
{
      "_id": ObjectId("607fbeeb0a752a66a7af40eb"),
      "address": {
        "loc": [
          -1,
          3
        ],
        "_id": "5d35d55d3d081f486d0d401c",
        "apartment": "",
        "description": "ACcdg dfef"
      },
      "approvedAt": ISODate("2021-04-21T11:28:05.295+05:30"),
      "assignedAt": null,
      "billingAddress": {
        "description": ""
      },
      "createdAt": ISODate("2021-04-21T11:28:04.449+05:30"),
      "creditCard": "",
      "deliveryDate": "04/21/21",
      "deliveryDateObj": ISODate("2021-04-21T12:27:58.746+05:30"),
      "owner": "609bd5831b912947ea51a9ac",
      "products": [
        "5a070c079b"
      ],
      "updatedAt": ISODate("2021-04-21T11:28:05.295+05:30"),
      
    }
```

and for users, it is like below

```
{
      "_id": ObjectId("609bd5831b912947ea51a9ac"),
      "updatedAt": ISODate("2021-05-12T18:47:55.291+05:30"),
      "createdAt": ISODate("2021-05-12T18:47:55.213+05:30"),
      "email": "1012@gmail.com",
      "phone": "123",
      "dob": "1996-04-10",
      "password": "",
      "stripeID": "",
      "__t": "Customer",
      "name": {
        "first": "A",
        "last": "b"
      },
      "orderCount": 1,
      "__v": 0,
      "forgottenPassword": ""
    }
```

Comment: post some example documents.

Comment: @turivishal is that what you want turivishal in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that after using createIndex for the owner field which is used to compare the owner in the orders from the users _id filed, so just after adding an db.orders.createIndex({ owner: 1 }), the query will run much faster and smoother

Answer (score 1):

- convert `_id` to string in lookup's let and you can remove `$addFields` from lookup pipeline
- add `$project` stage in lookup pipeline and show only required fields
- `$project` to show required fields and get last / max `createdAt` date use $max, you don't need to `$unwind` and `$group` operation

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "orders",
      let: { id: { $toString: "$_id" } },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$owner", "$$id"] } } },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            createdAt: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "orders"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      email: 1,
      name: 1,
      orderCount: { $size: "$orders" },
      phone: 1,
      lastOrder: { $max: "$orders.createdAt" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rdYU6DxnaaN)

> SUGGESTION:
>
> - You can save owner id in orders as objectId instead of string and whenever new order arrive store it as objectId, you can prevent conversation operator `$toString` operation
> - create an index in `owner` field to make lookup process faster.

Comment: still while exporting the data time-out is coming, any way I can get the whole data out in Jason format

Comment: how you are exporting data?

Comment: using studio 3t feature to export data @turivishal

Comment: use mongo shell for export collection. see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25936760/8987128), first $out this query result in a collection and export it by command from mongo shell.

Comment: is there is any way around to optimize the query more as I don't want to add any thing to the collection as it it the production database, anything I can read and apply to optimize it would be a great help and thanks

Comment: i think there is no issue in query, if you are not able to export data then the problem in studio 3t execution time limit, I think there will be an option to increase execution time I am not sure.

Comment: i have tried changing the time but it didn't help

Comment: okay so i think there is huge data, use mongo shell for export. there is no connection between export daata and query.