# Sort collection permanently in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sorting

Whenever we do db.Collection.find().sort(), only our output is sorted, not the collection itself,

i.e. If i do db.collection.find() then i see the original collection, not the sorted one.

Is there any way to sort the collection itself insted of just sorting the output?

Exporting the sorted result into entire new collection would also work.

if i have numbered _id field.(like _id:1 , _id_2 , _id:3 and so on)

Comment: You can use orderby to sort your collection

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do this? There is no inherent 'order' to the stored documents. If you want to sort a particular field often, then create an index for it.

Comment: @rubyist that is the same as doing a sort(). What he's asking is if there is a way to sort of permanently sort the order documents are stored in a collection, which is not the case.

Comment: @TomSwifty Actually i'm new to mongodb and i was just wondering if i could do that or not, there's no particular reason. Also, can u xplain me a bit more about index

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no substitute for reading the manual: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/

Comment: in short though, indexes will make queries and sorts go orders of magnitude faster (so long as you construct them correctly)

Comment: Thnx for your help :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also I do not see any reason for doing this (index on the field on which you are going to sort it will help you to get this sort fast), here is a solution for your problem:

You have your test collection this way

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5273f6987c6c502364ddfe94"), "n" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5273f6e57c6c502364ddfe95"), "n" : 14}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5273f6ee7c6c502364ddfe96"), "n" : -5}
```

Then the following command will create a sorted collection for you

```
db.test.find().sort({n : 1}).forEach(function(e){
  db.testSorted.insert(e);
})
```

Completely the same way you can achieve with this (which I assume might perform a faster, but I have not done any testing):

```
db.testSorted.insert(db.test.find().sort({n : 1}).toArray());
```

And just to make this answer complete, also I understand that this is an overkill, you can do this with [aggregation framework option $out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19600746/1090562).

**Just to highlight**: with all this you can solve bigger problem: save into another collection some sort of modification/subset of previous collection.

Comment: Insertion order is only guaranteed for a [capped collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/), so this suggestion does not maintain a true sorted collection as you suggest. Documents in a normal collection are stored in [natural order](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-natural-order) which is affected by document moves (when the document grows larger than the record space allocated) and deletions (free space can be reused for inserted/moved documents). An index is the appropriate way to return documents in an expected sort order.

Comment: @Stennie thanks for telling me about the possible problem with moves. But I have not told that this will create a collection that will be sorted all the time afterwards. I just told that after the operation will be completed, the collection will be sorted. If you will do updates or new inserts in the collection, the order will not be preserved. I also highlighted that the only way is to do find with sort.

Answer (score 0):

Documents in a collection are stored in [natural order](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-natural-order) which is affected by document moves (when the document grows larger than the current record space allocated) and deletions (free space can be reused for inserted/moved documents).  There is currently (as at MongoDB 2.4) no option to control the order of documents on disk aside from using a [capped collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/), which is a fixed-size collection that maintains insertion order but is subject to a [number of restrictions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/#recommendations-and-restrictions).

An index is the appropriate way to efficiently return documents in an expected sort order.  For more information see: [Using Indexes to Sort Query Results](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/) in the MongoDB manual.

A related feature is a [clustered index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustered_index#Clustered), which would store documents on disk to match an index ordering.  This is not a current feature of MongoDB, although it has been requested (see [SERVER-3294](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3294)).