# Export mongodb aggregation framework result to a new file

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have produced some results through **mongodb aggregation framework**. So now I need to get those results to a file(text or any other format).

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: mongo dbname command.js > output.json

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104800/printing-mongodb-shell-output-to-file

Answer (score 1):

Check the [$out](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator in aggregation framework.

> $out operator takes the documents returned by the aggregation pipeline and writes
>   them to a specified collection. The $out operator lets the aggregation
>   framework return result sets of any size. The $out operator must be
>   the last stage in the pipeline.
>
> The command has the following syntax, where  is
>   collection that will hold the output of the aggregation operation.
>   $out is only permissible at the end of the pipeline:

```
db.<collection>.aggregate( [
     { <operation> },
     { <operation> },
     ...,
     { $out : "<output-collection>" }
] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my [answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19600746/1090562) how to export output of the aggregation framework to a new collection. After exporting to a new collection you can simply do [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongodump/).