# How to aggregate too large collection, the number of documents over than 10 billion

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I got the following errors. when I tried to aggregated it by **user_id** or distinct on **user_id**

`failed: exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size`

`failed: exception: distinct too big, 16mb cap`

I wonder know how to finish my tasks under very large collection ?

## data format

```
{
    user_id: "Jack",
    SYMPTOM_1: "flu",
    SYMPTOM_2: "cough",
    SYMPTOM_3: "cancer",
    datetime: "20140101",
}
```

## aggregation query

This query is tried to group **users** and append all the **symptoms** of **medical records** to each user

```
db.medical_records.aggregate([
    {
        "$sort": { "datetime": 1 }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$user_id",
            "symptom1":{
                "$push": {"symptom": "$SYMPTOM_1" ,"date": "$datetime"}
            },
            "symptom2":{
                "$push": {"symptom": "$SYMPTOM_2" ,"date": "$datetime"}
            },
            "symptom3":{
                "$push": {"symptom": "$SYMPTOM_3" ,"date": "$datetime"}
            },                        
           "first_date": { "$first": "$datetime" },
           "user_id": { "$first": "$user_id" },
           "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "user_id": "$user_id",
            "date": "$datetime",
            "symptom1": "$symptom1",
            "symptom2": "$symptom2",
            "symptom3": "$symptom3",
            "count": "$count",
            "_id": 1
        }
    }
],allowDiskUse=true)
```

### Expected output

```
{u'user_id': u'de96dsdase303c6c6439891c57901183c0e4c',
   u'symptom1': [{u'symptom': u'1479 ', u'date': u'20040910'}],
   u'symptom2': [{u'symptom': u'     ', u'date': u'20040910'}],
   u'symptom3': [{u'symptom': u'     ', u'date': u'20040910'}],
   u'count': 1,
   u'first_date': u'20040910'}
```

Comment: can you show what is the result for your aggregation looks like for a small set of documents?

Comment: I think that you can try to output the result of an aggregation framework to another collection with http://stackoverflow.com/a/19600746/1090562. I have not tested itt, hence a comment. Let me know whether it yields a resul

Comment: I think you should use $limit to reduce the returned document. As in MongoDB you can't write a query which returns a result greater than 16mb.

Comment: @proc: Could you explain why you create an array for each anyway numbered symptom? Wouldn't it be better to have an array of symptoms? Furthermore, the `$project` stage is totally redundant.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg because that is the original database design, I can not modify it. although it seems redundant.

Answer (score -1):

It appears like you are trying to use the allowDiskUse option which would likely solve your problem, but unfortunately you seem to have a syntactical error.

When you pass options to an operation, you need to pass these as an object surrounded by `{` and `}`.

What you are doing here is assign `true` to a new global variable `allowDiskUse` and pass the result of that assign operation to aggregate, which is just the value `true`.

Try replacing `],allowDiskUse=true)` with `], { allowDiskUse:true } )`

This allows you to circumvent the 16MB limit per aggregation stage. But keep in mind that it will still be a very slow operation.

Comment: I use `pymongo` not javascript, so the syntax seems no problem on mine